# Create a method to change the value of a string variable

Tags: java, string, variables, methods

I have used a contructor to set the initial values of the variables being used

```
   public String playerName;
   public int yearofBirth;
   public String membershipLevel;


   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class Player
    */
    public Player()
    {
     super();
     this.playerName = "Michaela";
     this.yearofBirth = 1986;
     this.membershipLevel = "Adult";
   }
```

What Im looking for is a method that will allow me to change the value of membershipLevel to a different string?

Comment: Google Java setter or "mutator" methods. Please. Also check the tutorials since this is in the first 1-2 chapters of any Java book or tutorial. It's a little bit sad that you didn't do this first, to be honest.

Comment: Thank you. Had been stuck on this, for some reason I couldn't find the correct section in the text, had been looking a setter methods, but couldn't find the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean `Setter` method. The most common way doing this is using some method like:

```
public void setMembershipLevel(String newMembershipLevel) {
    this.membershipLevel = newMembershipLevel;
}
```

But here, as your properties are all `public` so they can be accessed from anywhere. Therefore you can simply write

```
createdObject.membershipLevel = "New Membership Level";
```

But it's better to set `Access Specifier` of your properties, fit your needs to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Please, make you question clearer. you wrote a sentence with question mark in the end, the question mark does not make it a question.

and to set the `String` while you are running and the class has already created you need to set "setter" function.

just write a new function and name it ***setMembershipLevel*** and it will get `String` parameter. the `String` that the method gets get into the *membershipLevel*.

```
public void setMembershipLevel(String str)
{
    this.membershipLevel = str;
}
```

you will call the method and set the Variable to the new value. this gave it the name "setter".